# Counting by Day Using Datediff and having

Tags: sql

I have the following code:

```
select lastmodifieddate,datediff(day,hire_date__c,lastmodifieddate)
from sf_case_task_c
where status__c = 'Completed' and name = 'Review Intake'
group by lastmodifieddate, hire_date__c
having datediff(day,hire_date__c,lastmodifieddate) <= 2
order by lastmodifieddate desc
limit 100
```

it's shooting the following out:

```
2017-05-05 20:08:34  1
2017-05-05 20:07:42  2
2017-05-05 19:52:48  1
```

I'm trying to have it so that it'll display, under my given conditions:

```
2017-05-01 39
2017-05-02 89
2017-05-03 55
```

etc. To basically group the counts on the conditions day-by-day, I'm not sure if I'm to use to a correlated sub query, but I feel like I'm missing something incredibly obvious.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  My best guess is Teradata.

Comment: "I feel like I'm missing something incredibly obvious" - did you read the documentation of `datediff` of your database?